# How to read this line of code correctly - Interfaces as objects

Tags: c#, object

Given a line such as:

```
IEnumerable s = new List<int>() {1, 2};
```

I would read this line as:
Create a new instance of List where each member must have an int32 data type and name this instance "s" which is of type IEnumerable.

I am not sure if the last part of the sentence is correct or not. I mean the part "*which is of type IEnumerable*" since Interfaces used to be contracts (with possible implementations in c#8.0 +) and I am not sure if we can correctly refer to them as objects. In fact, the type of "s" in this case is a System.Collections.Generic.List not IEnumerable.

Thank you.

Comment: Interfaces are types, so yes it's correct to say `s` has type `IEnumerable`.

Comment: that is not valid c# code, you need `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: @Lee, thank you, if you place you comment in an answer I will mark it as such. One thing though, GetType says its a System.Collections.Generic.List

Comment: @pm100, thank you for your comment. It compiles.

Comment: I assure you it does nt  "CS0305 Using the generic type 'IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments"

Comment: @pm100, thanks again. I tested this with .NET 6.0 and VS 2022 - Maybe you used a different version. Please see an image here if you would: https://ibb.co/99ZbRrM

Comment: very interesting, also using .net 6 vs 2022 https://ibb.co/hy1jSTH

Comment: and here https://ideone.com/jIzAAj

Comment: I notice in your screen shot that you have not compiled program.cs as it has a * next to its name

Comment: pm100 in fact I did. Also https://ibb.co/BgXZZ3h -  It is very strange. I also found that the compiler at this link works https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_csharp_compiler

Comment: we will agree then that at least some versions of c# , including the windows vs2022 .net core 6 I have on my windows 10 machine says that its not valid. And If asked I would have said it was invalid (thats why I tested it to be sure)

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/online-compiler/ doesnt like it either

Comment: You get 'IEnumerable<T>' (and `List<T>`) from `using Systems.Collections.Generic`. You get `IEnumerable' from `using System.Collections'. If you include both you can forget the type name in the generic.

Comment: @pm100 , dmedine - Interesting!

Comment: @dmedine i see that too, I guess because IEnum<T> is still , at heart, an IEnum

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Because `List<T>` is in the same namespace as `IEnumerable<T>` you get the compiler warning about the missing generic argument, rather than the unknown type error which would prompt VS to search for and suggest `using System.Collections`.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman its a fatal error not a warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring the type of the variable tells the *compiler* how to treat the variable. *You* know that the object *referenced* by the variable is a `List` but the compiler does not. You could easily change the object referenced by `s` to some *other* type of collection, of pass `s` to a function that changes the variable it references, So all the compiler knows is that method and property calls will bound based on the `IEnumerable` interface. If you try to call a `List` method (like `Add`) that's not part of `IEnumerable` (or an extension method of `IEnumerable` like `Select`) on the variable, the compiler will not allow it.

So I think your sentence is accurate if you remember that the *variable* and the *object* that the variable references can be of different (but compatible) types.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sounds good except that "if you try to call a List method that is not part of IEnumerable..." - It is possible to run this code: Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", s.Sum(), s.Min(), s.Max()); True you can't run methods that change the elements value though.

Comment: Those are not `List` methods - they are extension methods from `Enumerable`. I've updated that in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just going to add another sentence to explain the **WHY?**

```
IEnumerable s = new List<int>() {1, 2};
```

I would read this line as:

> Create a new instance of List where each member must have an int32 data type and name this instance "s" which is of type IEnumerable.

The reason we specified IEnumerable instead of List as the variable `s` type is because when we expose or pass `s` around in the program we don't want callers to be able to Add/Remove from it. Lists support Add/Remove/etc, using an IEnumerable we only allow its values to be enumerated, which is useful for API scenarios.

Comment: Good point, also, could be part of a method signature.

Comment: Nice insight as to why. In my experience a class would normally implement a `List` in the method body (so that, for instance, you could add things to it) and clients would have `IEnumerable` or, more often `IReadOnlyList` in the signature of the method that uses, but cannot alter, the `List` itself. The code in the OP doesn't really show any context, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading it perfectly fine. Given the following expression:

```
IEnumerable s = new List<int>() {1, 2};
```

we say that `s` is a variable of type `IEnumerable` that refers to an instance of `List<int>` containing two elements.

Comment: I still don't know what 'reading it' means. I strongly disagree that it is right to 'say that `s` is a variable of type `IEnumerable`. For one thing, calling `GetType()` on `s` returns `List`. Also, a variable of type `IEnumerable` could be literally anything that implements it. E.g., I could make a class that implements this interface that opens a new Word document whenever you enumerate over it. `s` is a `List`. Declaring it as `IEnumerable` simply limits its behavior to `GetEnumerator`, but specifically the definition of `GetEnumerator` implemented in the source for `List`.

Comment: The reason that `GetType` returns a `List` for `s` is because that is what the variable refers to. However, the only operations you can perform on `s` are those that are exposed by the `IEnumerable` interface (unless you cast it to `List<int>`).

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you define `s` as a `List<int>`. It is not correct to say that `s` has type `IEnumerable` or even `IEnurerable<int>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace types
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable s = new List<int>();
            Console.WriteLine(s.GetType());
            if(s is IEnumerable<int> enumerableType)
                Console.WriteLine(enumerableType.GetType());
            if (s is List<int> listType)
                Console.WriteLine(listType.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

Perhaps what the OP is not understanding is that `List<T>` implements (among others) the interface `IEnumerable<T>`---from the source code:

```
public class List<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, IList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IReadOnlyList<T>, ICollection, IList
```

I am sure that I am explaining this all wrong in terms of implementation details and that the .NET honchos will correct me, but what this means in practice is that you can create a variable of `type` `IEnumerable<T>` that in fact *is* a `List<T>` and treat it as either type. But, since you declared it as `IEnurable<T>` you cannot use it as a `List<T>` without some extra syntax.

For example:

```
IEnumerable s = new List<int>();
s.Add(1);
```

will not compile because `IEnumerable` has no definition for `Add`. But you can do this:

```
IEnumerable s = new List<int>();
if(s is List<int> list)
     list.Add(1);
```

Much more practical is simply to declare it as `List<T>` because all `IEnumerable` does is enumerate and since `List` implements the interface you get that functionality without any extra code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware of all what you have stated and I mentioned that it is of type System.Collections.Generic.List - Still the question is how to read the line of code in the question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'how to read the line of code'. I think the answer pretty well explains all the matters of importance.

Comment: I guess if you mean how to interpret the instruction in English (which is a very inadequate way to explain the code) it would be 'create a variable that is a `List<int>` but can only be used as `IEnumerable<int>`'

Comment: Another thing occurs to me: as they always say, 'interfaces don't __do__ anything'. `List<T>` implements `GetEnumerator()` which is its contractual obligation to `IEnumerable`. It is the `List` that actually defines the enumeration procedure. In that sense, your `IEnumerable<int> s` is a `List<int>` that only has one callable method: `GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: I liked your way of stating it in English. However, in your last comment, "s" has many methods such as ToArray, Sum, etc. Not only 1 method.

Comment: No. `s` in this case only has one method: `GetEnumerator()`.  That is, of course, unless you recast it as `List` which has many, many methods. This is in my answer. This is exactly why English is not sufficient for explaining these things.

Comment: In what universe is this not a useful answer?

Comment: I did not downvote. Note that one could invoke at least 3 methods on "s" - For example:   Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", s.Sum(), s.Min(), s.Max());

Comment: My compiler does not let me do that unless I explicitly typecast `s` as a `List`. It invokes error `CS1061: 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Sum'...` which makes sense, because the only method `IEnumerable` has is `GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: It works on my machine Windows 11, VS 2022, .NET 6.0

Comment: That is very odd. I upgraded to target .NET 6.0 and C# 10 and I still get that error. Furthermore, Jeremy Thompson's answer indicates that this restriction is exactly the reason you would prefer declaring `s` as `IEnumerable` over `List`.

Comment: Not sure why you are not getting the same behaviour I am observing. However, Jeremy Thompson's answer is about restricting operations that would "change" the collection value(s).

Comment: It is correct to say `s` has type `IEnumerable` since it's explicitly stated to have that type. This answer confuses the runtime result of `GetType()` as the 'type' of the bound variable. In static languages types are checked at compile time and explains why e.g. `s.Add(3)` will fail to type check even though it would be valid at runtime.